# Running puppeteer with Firefox on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firefox, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I'm trying to run puppeteer with Firefox on AWS lambda for printing PDFs.

My AWS Lambda Layer: nodejs->node_modules

node_modules contains Firefox binaries, as it works in my local dev environment.

Lambda Function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    product: 'firefox',
    headless: true
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://google.com/");
  console.log("loaded");
  
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

The error that I get

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Could not find expected browser (firefox) locally. Run `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install` to download a supported Firefox browser binary.",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Could not find expected browser (firefox) locally. Run `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install` to download a supported Firefox browser binary.",
    "    at FirefoxLauncher.launch (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Launcher.js:194:23)",
    "    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:8:21)"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to fix it? Firefox is super important for me since it supports OpenType SVG fonts.

Comment: You are probably not running Linux on your local machine? AWS Lambda runs Linux. So the Firefox binary in your `node_modules` needs to be the Linux version. But when you run `npm install` locally on a Windows machine and then deploy the `node_modules`, you are deploying the Windows version of Firefox.

Comment: I tried fixing this. Event went ahead and configured an EFS since Firefox for ubuntu was 284 MB, and AWS Lambda layers only allow 250 MB. But now I am getting this.

{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Failed to launch the browser process!\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Failed to launch the browser process!",

Comment: Please update your questions text with the update information and complete error message.